How can I add a new Styles option in Wordpress 2024 theme?
The Wordpress 2024 theme allows one to choose from a range of pre-defined styles from the full site editor (editor -> styles), with a choice that impact the entire website. One can further customize each style. I am looking for a way to add a new style configuration option to the selections found in the full site editor, and I can't find a way to do that.
The reason I want to add a new style option is because choosing a different style in the styles menu and then going back to my adjusted style seems to override my configurations and reset to default.

have you looked at child themes?

Did anyone respond to this question? I tried making a custom style json file. I duplicated the ember.json file, updated the file name to asf.json, and updated the code "title", replaced some palette colors and font families. I then added it to the themes>twentytwentyfour>styles directory along with the ember.json, fossil.json, etc. files. I then logged out and back into my site but I'm still not seeing it show in the editor Styles menu of alternate styles. I then logged back out and cleared my browser cache but that didn't help. Any thoughts or suggestions would be great. Thanks.
